# When does Flask store the user's authentication?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login

I created this form:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="POST">
          <div class="row">
            <div>
              <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="validate">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div>
              <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="validate">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" id="login" >Login</button>
        <br>
    </form>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

and I have this Flask app that uses `HTTPBasicAuth` to do authentication.

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request, make_response, url_for
from flask import render_template
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth

#Needs: pip install flask-httpauth

app = Flask(__name__)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
@auth.login_required
def login():
    print('in login')
    print(request.values.get('email'), request.values.get('password'))
    templateToReturn = 'login.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('in post')
        username = request.values.get('email')
        password = request.values.get('password')
        if verify_password(username, password):
            print('password verified')
            templateToReturn = 'index.html'
    print('Curr user', auth.current_user())
    print('request: ', request.method)
    if request.method == 'GET' and auth.current_user():
        templateToReturn = 'index.html'
    return render_template(templateToReturn)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    return render_template('logout.html')

@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(email, password):
    print('in verify pwd')
    return verifyAuthentication(email, password)
    
def verifyAuthentication(email, password):
    knownUsers = {'p1@gmail.com': 'pass', 
                  'p2@yahoo.com': 'pass'}
    authenticated = False
    if email in knownUsers:
        if knownUsers[email] == password:
            authenticated = True
    return authenticated
```

When I click the `submit` button of the form, I'm taken to the `login()` function. But isn't there supposed to be some way that it should go to the `verify_password()` function because it's decorated with `@auth.verify_password`?

How exactly and in which part of the code does the user authentication get registered with Flask? By which I mean: When does the `@auth.login_required` decorator actually allow their corresponding decorated functions to get executed?

Even the official page of `HTTPBasicAuth()` didn't explain this with an HTML example. Could someone please explain by adding to my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add name attribute in your HTML input tag, so ideally it should be -

```
 <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="validate" />
 <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="validate" />
```